# Need advice for update opencart from 2.x to 3.x

Tags: php, opencart

How to update opencart from 2.x to 3.x?.
Is there is any tool for this?
Or we need to do in manually(ftp file replace)?
Anyone can suggest a solution for this ?

Comment: Please follow official OpenCart documentation for that- http://docs.opencart.com/upgrading/

Comment: Thanks @HarnishDesign